# GPS Calculator conversion, calculate lat/lon value for new point

Tags: c#, gps, latitude-longitude

Here is problem which i have:

I load image in C#. On that image I have to insert 2 points: point A and point B by clicking mouse on random possitions.

Point A have it cords (Xa, Ya) which is read from program and I need to manually insert its GPS coords (LatitudeA and LongtudeA) for it.

Point B have it own cords (Xb, Yb) which is also read from program and I need to manually insert its GPS coords (LatitudeB and LongtudeB) for it.

So main problem is next: on every next click on screen I have to know GPS cords for that point. Also for that point C i have (Xc, Yc).

Here is my ComputeLatitudeAndLogitude method, but it seems it doesnt works perfectly. I need this on street level size.

Example:

A (487, 361, 45.252464, 19.850337)

B (1167, 397, 45.252026, 19.853990)

C (810, 513, ??? , ???);  results should be C(810, 513, 45.251592 , 19.852075)

PLEASE feel free to contact me so we can fix problem, mymailis hladnopivo1990@gmail.com

```
public void ComputeLatitudeAndLogitud (Wpf_Maps.Point point)
{
        int diffX = pointA.X - pointB.X;
        int diffY = pointA.Y - pointB.Y;
        double diffLatitude = pointA.Latitude - pointB.Latitude;
        double diffLongitude = pointA.Longitude - pointB.Longitude;
        double latitudePerPixel = Math.Abs(diffLatitude / diffX);
        double longitudePerPixel = Math.Abs(diffLongitude / diffY);

        int diffXforA = pointA.X - point.X;
        int diffYforA = pointA.Y - point.Y;
        int diffXforB = pointB.X - point.X;
        int diffYforB = pointB.Y - point.Y;

        double newLatitudeFromA = pointA.Latitude + (diffXforA * latitudePerPixel);
        double newLatitudeFromB = pointB.Latitude + (diffXforB * latitudePerPixel);

        double newLongitudeFromA = pointA.Longitude + (diffYforA * longitudePerPixel);
        double newLongitudeFromB = pointB.Longitude + (diffYforB * longitudePerPixel);

        point.Latitude = (newLatitudeFromA + newLatitudeFromB) / 2;
        point.Longitude = (newLongitudeFromA + newLongitudeFromB) / 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the distance you need to cover, linear extrapolation will not work too good; the earth is not plain, and latitude distances vary with longitude.

One approximation would be a sphere on which you calculate the [Great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

(GPS) coordinates are usually recorded relative to a (non-sphere) model of the earth, the [WGS-84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)  ellipsoid being the most common today. So for maximum accuracy, you'll have to calculate distances based on the corresponding reference model.

Additionally, if the reference model of the image is different from that of the GPS coordinates you may need more than two reference points to determine the exact mapping.

Comment: i need it on street level, so linear extrapolation will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I presume pointA and pointB are at opposite corners of the map, A being bottom left (or top left?)... meaning every point C is up and right of the point A.

Try this simplification:

```
    public void ComputeLatitudeAndLogitud (Wpf_Maps.Point point)
    {
        int diffX = pointA.X - pointB.X;
        int diffY = pointA.Y - pointB.Y;
        double diffLatitude = pointA.Latitude - pointB.Latitude;
        double diffLongitude = pointA.Longitude - pointB.Longitude;
        double latitudePerPixel = Math.Abs(diffLatitude / diffX);
        double longitudePerPixel = Math.Abs(diffLongitude / diffY);

        int diffXforC = point.X - pointA.X;
        int diffYforC = point.Y - pointA.Y;

        point.Latitude = pointA.Latitude + (diffXforC * latitudePerPixel);
        point.Longitude = pointA.Longitude + (diffYforC * longitudePerPixel);
   }
```

Comment: I click random on loaded image which is map for Point A, and random on map for Point B. 
Need to enter Latitude and Longitude for A and B.

Program need to recalculate Longitude and Latitude for every next point i randomly click on my image.

Comment: Hmm... now that I re-read your post, you're saying that A and B are random.  What if they have the same X or Y?  All sorts of things will go wrong.  You can't calculate latPerPixel without a delta.

Comment: How did you set the Latitude and Longitude properties for pointA and pointB?  Why can't you set pointC that way too?

Comment: i have text box where i input latitude and longitude for points A and B.

Cant set that way for C, because i dont know which point i need, it depends on situation

Comment: I think my code sample above should work.  The problem I'm seeing above is your attempt to average the differences between A and C and B and C.  There is no need to do that.  If you map out points ABC on a piece of paper using XY coordinates and then AB again using lat and long, and then C again using your average of the differences method, you'll see your second point C getting pulled away.  Calculate the latPerPixel and longPerPixel in those 6 lines as you are, then calculate diffXforC using a single anchor point (A in my example above), then add the difference in lat/long to that anchor.

Comment: Have (X, Y) cords on all points A, B and C, have Lat and Long for A and B, which I input from text box, i need point C (Lat, Long) to be calculated for data I wrote.

Comment: There's probably a bug in my code:  `int diffXforC = point.X - pointA.X; int diffYforC = point.Y - pointA.Y;` should probably be `int diffXforC = pointA.X - point.X; int diffYforC = pointA.Y - point.Y;`.

Comment: I will explain one more thing. I go to, for example to bing maps from browser, zoom to street level and print screen. Then load that image into my program. Mouse click for point A on image, insert (Lat,Lon) for A, mouse click for point B on image, insert (Lat,Lon) for B. Program doing its calculations for point C everywhere on map, right? So when i move mouse again to point B, it should write (Lon, Lat) which needs to be same as inserted. But they didnt. Lat is exactly in digit, but lon isnt. When i move over where point A was, i got (lat,lon) exactly as i entered.

Comment: The code sample above gives that result, at least it does when I run it!  If pointC XY matches A or B, the lat and long will match A or B.  For what values of A (X, Y, Lat, Long), B (X, Y, Lat, Long), and C (X, Y) does my code fail?

Comment: A(X, Y, Lat, Long) and B(X, Y, Lat, Long) is fixed points on image, I cant change it after i enter values (Lat,Long) for both of them.
I can change point C by clicking anywhere on map to get (Lat,Long) for it. If i click on (X,Y) coords which is exactly like A(X,Y), i give (Lat,Long) values for point C exactly like A(Lat, Long). If i click on (X,Y) coords which is exactly like B(X,Y), i give Latitude value right, but Longitude value wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my full code.  I've got three tests cases there.  The first is where pointC is somewhere random, in the second, pointC matches pointA, and in the third, pointC matches pointB.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ComputeLatitudeAndLongitude(new MyPoint(0, 0, 10, 10), new MyPoint(100, 100, 40, 40), new MyPoint(20, 40));
            ComputeLatitudeAndLongitude(new MyPoint(0, 0, 10, 10), new MyPoint(100, 100, 40, 40), new MyPoint(0, 0));
            ComputeLatitudeAndLongitude(new MyPoint(0, 0, 10, 10), new MyPoint(100, 100, 40, 40), new MyPoint(100, 100));
        }

        public void ComputeLatitudeAndLongitude(MyPoint pointA, MyPoint pointB, MyPoint pointC)
        {
            int diffX = pointA.X - pointB.X;
            int diffY = pointA.Y - pointB.Y;
            double diffLatitude = pointA.Latitude - pointB.Latitude;
            double diffLongitude = pointA.Longitude - pointB.Longitude;
            double latitudePerPixel = Math.Abs(diffLatitude / diffX);
            double longitudePerPixel = Math.Abs(diffLongitude / diffY);

            int diffXforC = pointC.X - pointA.X;
            int diffYforC = pointC.Y - pointA.Y;

            pointC.Latitude = pointA.Latitude + (diffXforC * latitudePerPixel);
            pointC.Longitude = pointA.Longitude + (diffYforC * longitudePerPixel);

            LogResults(String.Format("pointA X:{0} Y:{1} Lat:{2} Long:{3}", pointA.X, pointA.Y, pointA.Latitude, pointA.Longitude), true);
            LogResults(String.Format("pointB X:{0} Y:{1} Lat:{2} Long:{3}", pointB.X, pointB.Y, pointB.Latitude, pointB.Longitude), true);
            LogResults(String.Format("pointC X:{0} Y:{1} Lat:{2} Long:{3}", pointC.X, pointC.Y, pointC.Latitude, pointC.Longitude), true);
            LogResults(String.Empty, true);
        }

        public void LogResults(string message, bool insertNewline)
        {
            txtResults.Text += message + (insertNewline ? Environment.NewLine : String.Empty);
        }
    }

    public class MyPoint
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public double Latitude = 0;
        public double Longitude = 0;

        public MyPoint(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public MyPoint(int x, int y, double latitude, double longitude) : this(x, y)
        {
            Latitude = latitude;
            Longitude = longitude;
        }
    }
```

Results:

```
pointA X:0 Y:0 Lat:10 Long:10
pointB X:100 Y:100 Lat:40 Long:40
pointC X:20 Y:40 Lat:16 Long:22  // C.X is 20% of the way from A.X to B.X, so C.Lat is 20% of the way from A.Lat to B.Lat, Y/Long are 40%

pointA X:0 Y:0 Lat:10 Long:10
pointB X:100 Y:100 Lat:40 Long:40
pointC X:0 Y:0 Lat:10 Long:10  // C.X = A.X and C.Y = A.Y, therefore C.Lat and C.Long = A.Lat and A.Long

pointA X:0 Y:0 Lat:10 Long:10
pointB X:100 Y:100 Lat:40 Long:40
pointC X:100 Y:100 Lat:40 Long:40  // C.X = B.X and C.Y = B.Y, therefore C.Lat and C.Long = B.Lat and B.Long
```

Comment: anyway i can contact you so i send you my project? my mailis: djokic.nemanja@hotmail.com. 
I need these cords on street level: so you shoud probably try input for example: A: (45.252164 19.850331) B: (45.252028 19.853984).

Comment: i tested your formula for my test examples and results are next:

A(487, 361, 45.252164, 19.850337);
B(1169, 397, 45.252026, 19.853990);

 Calculations start:

C = A is (487, 361, 45.252164, 19.850337) right values;
C = B is (1169, 397, 45.252302, 19.853990) Lat is Wrong;

C random on map (810, 513, 45.252229, 19.865344) Lat/Lon is Wrong;
true value of C should be (810, 513, 45.251592, 19.852075)

Comment: @NemanjaDjokic Yeah, I see your point now.  I have no idea what's going on.  There's either a silly little bug in the algorithm or in our understanding of the problem.  I'll take another look at it later.  Let me know if you come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It cant be done with code above i wrote. Constant EARTH_RADIUS MUST me implemented in function for calculation, if we want to get high precision (6 digits at least: n,mmmmmm). Next code will scale proper lat/lon per pixel, so calculated point C will match referent points A and B when we put that (X,Y) cords which points A and B have.

public void ComputeLatitudeAndLogitude(Wpf_Maps.Point point){

```
        double diffLatAB = pointB.Latitude - pointA.Latitude;
        double diffLonAB = pointB.Longitude - pointA.Longitude;

        int diffXAB = pointB.X - pointA.X;
        int diffYAB = pointB.Y - pointA.Y;

        int diffXAC = point.X - pointA.X;
        int diffYAC = point.Y - pointA.Y;

        point.Latitude = diffLatAB / diffXAB * diffXAC + pointA.Latitude;
        point.Longitude = diffLonAB / diffYAB * diffYAC + pointA.Longitude;
   }
```